# Implicit without explicit imports?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to get implicits from companion objects without explicit imports?

I have the following case:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def foo(f: A): String
}

case class Bar(name: String)

object Bar {
  implicit object FooBar extends Foo[Bar] {
    def foo(f: Bar) = f.name
  }
}

class TestImplicits[T] {
  def sayFoo(t: T)(implicit ev: Foo[T]) = ev.foo(t)

  def sayFooIndirect(t: T) = sayFoo(t)
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to instantiate TestImplicits and call the sayFooIndirect method without needing to tunnel the implicit through it to the sayFoo method.

```
val b = new Bar("test")
val t = new TestImplicit[Bar]
t.sayFooIndirect(b)
```

However the code doesn't compile:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Foo[T]
     def sayFooIndirect(t: T) = sayFoo(t)
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is, you can't

```
class TestImplicits[T] {
  def sayFoo(t: T)(implicit ev: Foo[T]) = ev.foo(t)
  def sayFooIndirect(t: T) = sayFoo(t)
}
```

`sayFoo` takes a parameter `ev`, that *must* be provided when you are calling it, explicitly or implicitly.

In body of `sayFooIndirect` no implicit object of type `Foo[T]` is available. To make it available, either pass it implicitly everywhere or use some other way to put it in scope. As your class is fixed with type `T`, you could take implicit `Foo[T]` in constructor.

```
class TestImplicits[T](implicit ev: Foo[T]) {
  def sayFoo(t: T) = ev.foo(t)
  def sayFooIndirect(t: T) = sayFoo(t)
}
```

Using this approach following will work:

```
val b = new Bar("test")
val t = new TestImplicits[Bar]
t.sayFooIndirect(b)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was far too focused on adding the implicit to the method where I needed the implicit. But adding it to the constructor works nicely in my use case.